# Copying worksheets between workbooks - Excel interop

Tags: c#, excel, excel-formula

I copy worksheets from one workbook and paste them into a second workbook.
I use this code:

```
book = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(@"e:\tr\pliki\filename.xlsm",
                       Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
                       Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
                       Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
                       Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Global global = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.GlobalClass();
            sheet.Copy(Missing.Value, global.Sheets[5]);
            book.Save();
```

All works fine, but the problem is with the formulas. After worksheet has been copied formulas in it refer to values in the first workbook. The formulas paths contains paths to first workbook from which its was copied:

```
='E:\tr\pliki\[filename.xlsm]worksheetA'!A1:E2
```

and should be like this:

```
='worksheet'!A1:E2
```

Does anyone help me ?

Comment: you should accept answers from your previous questions: if you don't care about answers that were given to you, why would we care about your new questions... you can accept an answer by clicking on the tick on the left of the answer that fits best to your issue

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that I should accept answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of a clean way to do what your trying to do, anyway this is a workaround that could solve your problem. It's simply a matter of changing formulas to text before copying the worksheet and restore everything after that. I.e. you can replace all the = in your cells with some string which you know is not present in your data (e.g. something weird like X_X_X_X_X_X) and then revert to the initial situation.

The code could be something like this:

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application appExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook srcBook = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(@"c:\tmp\test.xls",
                   Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
                   Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
                   Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
                   Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook destBook = appExcel.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet srcSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)srcBook.Worksheets[1];
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range usedRange = srcSheet.UsedRange;
        usedRange.Replace("=", "X_X_X_X_X_X", Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
        srcSheet.Copy(destBook.Worksheets[1], Missing.Value);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet destSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)destBook.Worksheets[1];
        usedRange.Replace("X_X_X_X_X_X", "=", Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
        usedRange = destSheet.UsedRange;
        usedRange.Replace("X_X_X_X_X_X", "=", Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
```

Comment: Ok, it works, I change your code to this:
sheetDst = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)book.Worksheets["AAA"];
            range1 = sheetDst.get_Range("A1", "E2");
            Object[] argsA = new Object[1];
            argsA[0] = formula1;
            range1.GetType().InvokeMember("Formula", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, range1, argsA);
            range1 = sheetDst.get_Range("A1", "E2");
and it works fine.